# Quotation marks vs Italics for sourcing articles

Tags: commas, quotation-marks, italics

I wanted to source an online article (just a regular one, not part of a longer work) and was unsure whether to use quotation marks or italics. I know that it is generally advised to use quotation marks for shorter sources, but I have heard conflicting thoughts. Also, I should not use a comma in front of the title right?

Without Comma: I read an article titled "Climate Change".

With Comma: I read an article titled, "Climate Change".

I would assume the first one is better because it the title is an essential phrase

Comment: Regarding italics vs. quotation marks, rigorous rules for the matter are the province of scholarly style manuals (MLA, APA, CMS, etc.). Choice among these, in contexts scholarly enough to call for any, is more usually up to the editor (or professor) than up to the writer. But part of the purpose of such codified systems for documenting sources is to get rid of such verbiage as "I read an article titled."

Comment: Why would you need a comma? It's essentially the same structure as "We met a man christened Fred; I visited house named 'The Laurels'; They sailed to America on a ship called 'The Mayflower'. None of those needs a comma.